# Почему не удаляется существующий файл в Python?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

В некотором месте программы содержится такой код:

```
if os.path.isfile('./'+filename):
    print(os.path.isfile('./'+filename))
    subprocess.Popen('rm ./'+filename).wait()
```

Он вызывает ошибку FileNotFound, несмотря на то, что файл существует (во-первых печатается True, а во вторых после завершения программы файл остается на диске). Я понимаю, что это далеко не самый лучший способ удалить файл, но хотелось бы знать, почему этот код не работает.

UPD. Забыл упомянуть, что этот файл появляется путем скачивания с помощью wget  и иногда бывает пустой (отсутствие файла на сервере).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> On POSIX, if args is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or path of the program to execute. However, this can only be done if not passing arguments to the program.

Если в `subprocess.Popen` в качестве первого аргумента передается строка, то в POSIX системах (в том числе в linux) это может быть только строка содержащая имя выполняемой программы или путь до нее. Без аргументов. Если нужно передать также и аргументы, вместо строки используйте список.

```py
subprocess.Popen(['rm', './' + filename]).wait()
```

Вот только конкретно с этой задачей лучше справится [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove)

```py
os.remove('./' + filename)
```

Если строка `filename` будет пустой, то условие `isfile` скорее всего не сработает никогда, потому, что `'./'` это каталог, а не файл. Но на всякий случай делайте проверку явно.

```py
if filename and os.path.isfile('./' + filename):
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, к сожалению проблема оказалась совершенно в другой части программы.

Comment: А вместо ‘./‘ лучше всё-таки `getcwd()`, да и ‘/‘ правильнее через `os.path.join()`получать...

Comment: @0andriy намеренно оставил `'./'` как есть в вопросе, и то, только потому, что `'./' + '/etc/passwd'` и  `'/etc/passwd'` это действительно разные пути, иначе убрал бы вовсе. От `'./' + '../../../etc/passwd'` это все равно не спасет. Если уж советовать, как правильно, то от начала и до конца, без полумер. А это явно за рамками темы вопроса.